# How to escape HCL string containing ${aws:username} in ${jsonencode(terraform template)}?

Tags: amazon-web-services, templates, terraform

Is there a possibility to process through `jsonencode` this macros `${aws:username}` in a template?

I'm trying to pass variable: `Owner = ["$${aws:username}"]` or `Owner = ["&{aws:username}"]` to terraform template but I have got error:

1. in case `&&`: *Error: failed to render : <template_file>:1,400-401: Extra characters after interpolation expression; Expected a closing brace to end the interpolation expression, but found extra characters.*
2. in case `&`- jsonencoded to `"\u0026{aws:username}"` which doesn't work in IAM

```hcl
locals {
  enforce_tag = {
    Environment = ["development", "production", "rnd", ]
    Project     = ["snooper", "tom"]
    Owner       = ["$${aws:username}"]
  }
}
```

```hcl
data "template_file" "enforcetags" {
  template = templatefile("${path.module}/enforcetags_iterate_over_map.tpl",
    {
      key_tag   = [for key, value in local.enforce_tag : key]
      value_tag = local.enforce_tag
    }
  )
}
```

**Template:**

```hcl
${jsonencode(
    {
        "Version" = "2012-10-17",
        "Statement" = [
            {
                "Sid" = "VisualEditor0",
                "Effect" = "Allow",
                "Action" = "ec2:*",
                "Resource" = "*",
                "Condition" = {
                    "ForAllValues:StringEquals" = {
                        "aws:TagKeys" : key_tag
                    },
                    "StringEqualsIfExists" = {
                        for key in key_tag : "aws:RequestTag/${key}" => value_tag[key]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
)}
```

I'm expecting to get JSON like this:

```json
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "ec2:*",
            "Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                    "aws:TagKeys": [
                        "Environment",
                        "Owner",
                        "Project"
                    ]
                },
                "StringEqualsIfExists": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/Environment": [
                        "development",
                        "production",
                        "rnd"
                    ],
                    "aws:RequestTag/Owner": [
                        "${aws:username}"
                    ],
                    "aws:RequestTag/Project": [
                        "snooper",
                        "tom"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0"
        }
    ],
    "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```

Thank you in advance.

**Solution:** Matt and Martin inspired me to rework my code.

```hcl
resource "aws_iam_policy" "ec2_enforce_tags" {
  name        = "ec2_creating_enforce_tags"
  path        = "/"
  description = "To enforce predefined and corresponding keys and tags creating EC2 resources"
  policy = templatefile("${path.module}/enforcetags_iterate_over_map.tpl",
    {
      key_tag   = [for key, value in local.enforce_tag : key]
      value_tag = local.enforce_tag
    }
  )
  tags = {
     Type              = "enforce"
  }
}
```

Comment: You mention this is rendered in a template. Could you please share the template and the `templatefile` invocation in your config? You can trim the expected JSON to just the relevant part to keep the question compact.

Comment: Hello Matt, I have edited my question.

Comment: With this update to the question, I can see now how to answer the question in general. However, the expected JSON and template appear to be different. Could you please provide matching expected JSON and template? Also, you can assign the return of the `templatefile` function directly to the resource argument and avoid having to use the `data.template_file` entirely for your convenience.

Comment: I have edited JSON. I'm not sure about templatefile function directly because of this error in jsonencode precesses. Most probably, I don't understand well.

Comment: So unfortunately because the `${aws:username}` is a value assigned and returned in a `for` expression, you cannot relocate the `jsonencode` invocations in the template to not have `${aws:username}` within the argument. This is unfortunately what you would need to do (along with the double syntax `$${aws:username}` to achieve what you want. You will have to do this differently.

Comment: I would've expected `"$${aws:username}"` to work, since that's the documented way to escape the `${` sequence in Terraform string templates. The error you included in your question seems to be related to the `${` sequence in the template file itself, rather than the one in your template call, so I think you may have had a syntax error in your template when you tried that, which was a separate problem from escaping the `${aws:username}` sequence.

Comment: I'd suggest focusing on the `$${` solution, trying it again, and then editing your question to include the full error message and exact template and call source code you used _for that particular attempt_. Right now it's hard to understand exactly what happened because you've described two things you tried but only given one example, and so it's not clear which of the attempts that example relates to.

Comment: (Note that this `&{...}` variant is not a real AWS IAM syntax but is instead something special implemented by [the `aws_iam_policy_document` data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_policy_document), as an extra preprocessing step implemented inside the AWS provider source code. That won't work in any other context.)

Comment: Another problem here is that you are using both [the `templatefile` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/templatefile.html) _and_ [the deprecated `template_file` data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/template/latest/docs/data-sources/file) at the same time. You should remove all use of the `template_file` data source because it has not been necessary for template rendering since Terraform v0.12, and continues to exist only for Terraform v0.11 users.

Comment: Thank you, gentlemen. Matt and Martin inspired me to rework my code.
`$${aws:username}` - work well with the inline templatefile in a resource "aws_iam_policy". But doesn't work with `resource "local_file"` 

I have edited my question, added working code.